# multiple definition error in C++ related to linking error

Tags: c++, qt, class

I was defining a simple class called `Date` in C++. The IDE I'm using is Qt Creator. When I'm compiling, the compiler said that every function in this class has "multiple definitions". Below are the .cpp and .h files:

```
// date.h

#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include <string>

/* A class representing an earth day.*/

class Date {

public:
    /*construct a new day, initially assigned at Jan.1st.2000*/
    Date();

    /* take three numbers to create the date.*/
    Date(int cmonth,int cday, int cyear);

    /*clean up memory allocated to this data type*/
    ~Date();

private:
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

#endif // DATE_H
```

`

```
// date.cpp

#include "date.h"

Date::Date(){
    year=2000;
    month=1;
    day=1;
}

Date::Date(int cmonth,int cday, int cyear){
    month=cmonth;
    day=cday;
    year=cyear;
}

/*clean up memory allocated to this data type*/
Date::~Date(){
    //automatic
}
```

Sample Error Message:
D:samplepath\date.cpp:3: error: multiple definition of `Date::Date()'

One possible main cpp that could induce the error (basically anything):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum=0;
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've made sure that I avoided a few basic errors associated with this message, namely:

- I didn't put any implementation in the header.
- I used the #ifndef for protection
- I did a global search on keyword `Date` and did not find any conflict.
- I always use a new build to compile

Every function in this class have a "multiple definition of" error, but I can't tell what went wrong. Currently I'm doing an all-limb quadruple face palm. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: As it turns out, this is **indeed** a linker error. In the .pro file of Qt Creator, I included the source file twice with the following code:

```
SOURCES += $$files($$PWD/*.cpp) \
        date.cpp
```

**The second line of code "date.cpp" was actually automatically added here by Qt Creator**, if you create the new class through its menu.

Many thanks to all the guys here for your generous help!

Comment: You do need to define a destructor, if you have nothing to destruct.

Comment: Is this the only Date class? Try putting your class in a namespace.

Comment: any library with same class?

Comment: @tillaert you mean I don't need a destructor? And yes this is the only date class. I confirmed this with a global search. You mean adding std:: before every function protype in the header?

Comment: @hyde Question edited as per your request. And no, I did not include any .cpp file. If it would not be too much trouble for you, can you tell me how to check the linking？ I tried to look it up on the internet but it's confusing.

Comment: @Wayne in Qt Creator, look at "Compile output" (at the bottom of the screen). Find the link command, which has `-o executable_name` as part of it, and bunch of `.o` files to be linked.

Comment: So, this is really a problem with your `.pro` file it seems.

Comment: @Wayne The destructor will be automatically generated, so you can leave it if you do not need it. With namespaces, I meant that you put you Date class in your own namespace, instead of the global one.

Comment: @tillaert Thanks so much for explaining. Sorry I'm still quite new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built your code with this *qmake* `.pro` file, and it built and executed with expected output (`0`):

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    date.cpp

HEADERS += \
    date.h
```

Comment: I'll alter the .pro and get back to you later

Comment: Yes when I change the .pro file into this way. It did work. Then something must be wrong with my .pro. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Wayne I suggest you edit the question, now that you know what the actual problem is.

Comment: Many thanks. Really appreciate it. I could finally move my limbs away from my face.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a compiler error and not a linker error?  Maybe you have included the object file twice (in the .pro file).  Also, try putting default values in the declaration of the constructor, instead of overloading it:

```
Date(int cmonth=2000,int cday=1, int cyear=1);
```

Comment: The header guards (#ifndef DATE_H, #define DATE_H...) would protect the file if included twice in the .pro, assuming the OP is not including implementation files in his source.

Comment: @MrUser you should avoid using default values, because they give problems when using inheritance. It's better to use a parameter list. `Date():year(2000), month(1), day(1){}`

Comment: Thanks for your stylistic advice. But no, I did not #include the header in the .pro file.

Comment: I'm sorry for jumping to the conclusion. You are actually right the whole time. I just did not check the .pro close enough since the change was automatically made.